# PrimeFaces selector which includes inputs of components with hidden input fields

Tags: primefaces

I would like to use [PrimeFaces Selectors](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/searchexpression) to process all input components in a certain group, which includes several `p:rating` fields.

I minimized my use case to, XHTML:

```html
<h:form>
  <h:panelGroup styleClass="myGroup">
    <p:rating value="#{myBean.rating}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Save"
                     process="@(.myGroup :input)"
                     action="#{myBean.save()}"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

  private Integer rating; // Getter and setter are present

  public void save() {
    System.out.println("Rating: " + rating);
  }

}
```

With the above selector the rating is not processed. If I change the component to `p:inputText`, it is working. If I remove the process attribute, it is also working. I assume this has to do with the hidden input `p:rating` is using for its value.

My question: can you create a PrimeFaces selector which includes the inputs of components with hidden input fields?

Comment: Did you try `@(.myGroup :input :hidden)` ???

Comment: @Melloware oh, wow, that actually works! Can you create an answer out of it? This must also be added to the documentation.

Comment: I still don't get how this works. I thought the selectors kind of worked the same way CSS rules are working. To me the rule would read as all hidden input that are a child of any input, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:hidden` is a special Jquery selector not part of CSS.

See: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

So change your selector to:

```
@(.myGroup :input :hidden)
```

However I doubt it's a big deal in your case but make sure to read the "Additional Notes" section in the jQuery `:hidden` documentation.

An alternative which works as well in your case is using [`p:fragment`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/fragment.xhtml):

```html
<h:form>
  <p:fragment>
    <p:rating value="#{myBean.rating}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Save"
                     action="#{myBean.save()}"/>
  </p:fragment>
</h:form>
```

Comment: It still feels there is something not 100% right about this. In simple cases this was working for me when using Chrome, but on a more complex page it works when using Firefox, but not when using Chrome.

Comment: Do you know how these selectors are processed? Are they delegated to jQuery? In other words, should I be able to test them in my browsers JS console?

Comment: I so don't get this, but `@(.myGroup :hidden :input)` does seem to work in both Chrome and Firefox. Although I could create a small reproducer... that is what annoys me most.

Comment: I am not sure how the PFS Selector framework works but I was under the impression it used Jquery to select the items.

Comment: Indeed `p:fragment` is what I was looking for!